# Why is collections.Counter uppercase and collections.defaultdict is not?

Tags: python, collections, class-names, python-collections

Some of the elements in the `collections` module seem to be uppercase, some other not. Is there a specific rationale behind it?

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: Guess: what are the odds that a piece of code contains a *variable* called `counter` (which would shadow that name)? And `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3uoy8f/what_is_an_underused_tool_from_the_standard/cxgq54m) reddit comment

> All classes written in python are upper camel case.
>
> All types based on C code are lower. [like the primitives]
>
> `namedtuple` is a function, thus follows the naming convention of functions. `deque` and `defaultdict` are types, (C); `Counter` and `OrderedDict` are classes, (Python).